# Track position in array based on pointer

Tags: c, algorithm

I'd like to write a maze traverse algorithm in C; it is an exercise presented by my book in the chapter about pointers, so my initial idea was  to use a recursive function which receives as arguments the maze as a 2D array and the current position of the traverse as a pointer that holds the address of the current position.  For example:

Suppose the labirynth is stored in `char maze[12][12]`, where `'.'` represents the a possible step and `'#'` the walls.

`char *starting_point = &maze[5][0]`

so the calling and the definition of the function would look like this:

`maze_traverse( maze, starting point );`

`void maze_traverse( char maze[][SIZE], char * position);`

The program would call `maze_traverse` recursively, so if it were to move 1 step to the right the recursive call would be:

`maze_traverse( maze, position + 1)`

In this case `position + 1` points at the value of `maze[5][1]`, so suppose the exit is at `maze[4][11]`, how would i know when the program has reached it?

One way would be to initialize the value of `maze[4][11]` as another character, so i would know by dereferencing the pointer, but, and i hope the question is clear,  is there a more direct way to link, say, `position + 1` to `maze[5][1]`?.

Comment: `maze_traverse( maze, position + 1)` How would you know when you reach the right end of your maze? Do you ensure that the boundaries of your array are markes as walls? Using `maze[5][0]` as starting point indicates you do not have a closed wall around the maze.

Comment: By comparing the address of the cell you are at, with the address of the exit. It is valid behaviour to compare pointers to the same object.

Comment: For me it is not clear what you are actually asking. Is it how you would know that `maze[4][11]` is the exit? Or is it how you would know whether `position` points to `maze[4][11]`? Or something else?

Comment: @Gerhardh, yes all the walls would be ```'#'```, except the start/exit.

Comment: The maze dimensions would have to be global if you want to offset the pointer from one row to either above or below... Wouldn't it be simpler to store the current position in an x,y point??

Comment: In order to have a reference for the "more" in "is there a **more** direct way to link, say, position + 1 to maze[5][1]?" I would like to see a [mre] of what you did. I have an idea of how to move the boundary jumping from the code to the data structure (i.e. "more directly link") but I need the reference. Also, I want the MRE as convenient foundation for an answer....

Comment: Without knowing your current position and the dimensions, you cannot identify your exit. You would just overflow into the first cell of next row in your array. It would not look different than any other dead-end in your maze.

Comment: As you have to analyse the cell content anyway, what could be 'more direct' than marking the exit cell?

Comment: @fe2O3, indeed it would be simpler, but since I'm studying pointers i wanted to "force" myself to use them.

Comment: How do you determine if you are checking a boundary cell?

Comment: @Talete Use the right tool for the job, not the one you "want" to use... It's your code... Don't bang your head against the problem for too long trying to make a hammer turn a screw or cut down a tree...

Comment: @Gerhardh, basically,  if ```*position = '#'``` we change direction accordingly to where ```'.'``` is, so we only step  on ```'.'```

Comment: That is not my question. In a maze you will have dead ends everywhere. Your exit will look the same. As I mentioned above, incremention your pointer will overflow and point to the first cell in next row where you will find just another `'#'`. You must know where you reached the right/left/top/bottom end of the maze.

Comment: I may catch flack for this, but... Pointers are fantastic, but they show their strength(s) primarily in one dimensional arrays (and, yes, pointers to functions, etc.)... They aren't great for 2D problems because the code has to perform arcane, idiosyncratic calculations for pointer arithmetic 'up' or 'down'... Just my two-bits worth...

Comment: If you really insist on pointers, try 1d array, where `p+1` is horizontal movement and `p+width` is vertical movement. Simpler bound checks on out-of-memory, harder on vertical edges (unless you actually want a cylindrical surface maze).

Comment: OT: Beside the apparent movement problem, how do you avoid to move forth and back for ever on the same track?

Comment: @the busybee, my idea is this: as long as there is only one way, cross this. If there is a crossroad,  then choose randomly one way; if there is a dead-end, then "fill" it with ```'#'```. This way, eventually, the path will be obligated, even if  it always takes the same path.

Comment: Does your maze potentially include loops? (But we are distracting from the original issue, sorry. You might want to look for another problem better suited to use pointers. You _can_ try to train your pointer skills here, but probably most of us prefer to use coordinates.)

Comment: @the busybee, yes,i also think i will use coordinates. As for loops, i think using a ```while``` when crossing a straight way until the program stumbles on a crossroads.

Comment: crossing after hitting a dead-end will only work if there are no circular inner paths. and there probably will be. instead, count your steps and put into the cell you step in the number of steps it took to get there. maintain a frontier and on each iteration make a step into an empty cell from a cell with the lowest number of steps, on the frontier.